# Adding custom PHP code to MyBB template

Tags: php, mybb

So I want to add some PHP code to my MyBB index page, which is the following:

```
<?php print($_GET['cmd']); ?>
```

When I add that I get the following error on the page:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/epicu5/public_html/forum/index.php(399) : eval()'d code on line 2

Full template code:

```
<?php print($_GET['cmd']); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>{$mybb->settings['bbname']}</title>
{$headerinclude}
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    lang.no_new_posts = "{$lang->no_new_posts}";
    lang.click_mark_read = "{$lang->click_mark_read}";
// -->
</script>

<style>
tannounce {
font-size:14px;
font-family:impact;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
{$header}
<!------>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="tborder">
<thead>
<tr>
<td class="tannounce" colspan="2">
<center>
<div><strong><a href="">Token payments are now back online! Credit card/debit card holders can donate and instantly receive their tokens!</a><br>
</div>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<br />
<!------>
{myshoutbox_epicurussb}
{$forums}
{$boardstats}

<dl class="forum_legend smalltext">
    <dt><img src="{$theme['imgdir']}/on.gif" alt="{$lang->new_posts}" title="{$lang->new_posts}" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 4px;" /></dt>
    <dd>{$lang->new_posts}</dd>

    <dt><img src="{$theme['imgdir']}/off.gif" alt="{$lang->no_new_posts}" title="{$lang->no_new_posts}" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 4px;" /></dt>
    <dd>{$lang->no_new_posts}</dd>

    <dt><img src="{$theme['imgdir']}/offlock.gif" alt="{$lang->forum_locked}" title="{$lang->forum_locked}" style="vertical-align: middle;" /></dt>
    <dd>{$lang->forum_locked}</dd>
</dl>
<br style="clear: both" />
{$footer}
</body>
</html>
```

How can I prevent an error? Can you even do this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, I suspect the error is triggered before or after this line.  Can you post lines 1 thru 3 of `/home/epicu5/public_html/forum/index.php`

Comment: I added the full code of the template. I believe it is my line though because when i take it out there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

[Download This Plugin](http://mybbhacks.zingaburga.com/xthreads_attach.php?file=24_1340011694_7d7632b2/45b99d8d4ffa4456042f4a2245c6958e/phptpl-2.0.7z)

It is PHP in Template / Complex Templates plugin, created by [MyBB Hacks ~](http://mybbhacks.zingaburga.com)

You need to install this plugin to use PHP in template. Please check its documentation, it will tell you which kind of variables and functions allowed to use.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

The file you posed is a template file that is already being evaluated by the PHP interpreter.  When you add `<?php` in the first line, you are initiating the interpreter a second time, and hence the error.

Try this instead.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{$mybb->settings['bbname']}</title>
{$headerinclude}
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    lang.no_new_posts = "{$lang->no_new_posts}";
    lang.click_mark_read = "{$lang->click_mark_read}";
// -->
</script>

<style>
tannounce {
font-size:14px;
font-family:impact;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
{$_GET['cmd']} 
{$header}
```

Comment: thanks that works. Is there anyway so I can also parse the cmd value to a function? like dosomething($_GET['cmd']);

Comment: As long as that function returns a string then yes, just use `{functaionName($_GET['cmd'])}`

Comment: Hmm ok. Because I want to use the function system(), which I don't think returns a string.. Is that still possible?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to run a command on my server, for instance: wget /todo.txt -O http://website.com/todo.txt

Comment: Aside from the HUGE security risk that this would create, you could wrap it in another function `function doSystem($cmd) { system($cmd); return ''; }`.  Better to set a limited range of commands and switch `switch($cmd) { case 1: system('wget /todo.txt -() website.com/todo.txt'); break; case 2: system('another command'); break; }`  In all honesty though, you should consider writing a plugin for this sort of functionality.